# I wrote a custom state hook using useReducer. Is it dangerous to use? (React Ts)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I don't want to use single state variables or updating the whole state with functional components. I wrote a hook based on useReducer like below but I am not sure about the possible dangerous effects. Is it safe? Thanks.

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

export function useCustomState<T>(initialState: T) {
    const reducer: React.Reducer<T, Partial<T>> = (prevState, newState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        ...newState,
    });

    return useReducer(reducer, initialState, (state) => state);
}
```

Comment: Just use gloves and you should be ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not *dangerous*, but I think it's also not the best way to accomplish your goals.  It seems like you're not understanding the differences between `useState` and `useReducer` and when you should use one or the other.

A "reducer" is a function that takes the previous state and an "action" and returns a new state.  The action meant to be an instruction rather a state -- it's the job of the reducer to determine the next state based on that instruction.  An action typically looks like `{type: 'LOGGED_OUT'}` or `{type: 'LOGGED_IN', payload: { userId: 12345, username: 'Some One' }`.

In your case, your "action" is the new state which you want to shallow merge with the existing state.  In my opinion, you would be better off using `useState` to achieve this.

```
export function useCustomState<T>(initialState: T) {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

    const update = (newState: Partial<T>) =>
        setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            ...newState,
        }));

    return [state, update]
}
```

This hook returns a tuple that is similar to your typical `[state, setState]` tuple, except that the `update` function can accept a partial state that it will merge with the existing state.

Comment: Thanks. I create the hook with useReducer because it is clearly providing the previous state in the reducer function which i think is a safer way of using the prev state for merge operation and i was not know that useState's dispatch function also provides this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is nothing wrong with writing a custom hook that wraps one or more existing hooks and adds logic or code that you do not want to duplicate.

You can see an example doing something similar [on the React documentation about custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook).